# Grant permission for custom role from hook_install programmatically

Tags: 8, users, hooks, installation

Drupal Version: 8.5.5

Need to assign permission to existing role during module installation:
Am using below code in hook_install:

```
use Drupal\user\RoleInterface;
use Drupal\user\UserInterface;
function hook_install() {

 $permission = 'test permission';
    $tester_rid = RoleInterface::TESTER;

    if ('tester' == Role::load($tester_rid)) {
      $tester_role->grantPermission($permission);
      $tester_role->save();
    }
}
```

Above grant permission is not working.
I have also tried with

```
user_role_grant_permissions(RoleInterface::ANONYMOUS_ID, array(
      'my custom permission',
    ));
user_role_grant_permissions(RoleInterface::TESTER, array(
      'my custom permission',
    ));
```

Above hook_install is not working.

Pls help

Comment: Hey hey, welcome back to Drupal Answers. Above information is not sufficient to let us help you. We don't provide a debugging service scanning through your code to find out what exactly you want. Please update your question and properly explain what your are trying to do **and why**.

Comment: `Entity::load` return an entity, not a string. You can't compare it with a string and expect a useful result

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
use Drupal\user\Entity\Role;

function mymodule_install() {
  $role_object = Role::load('my custom role name');
  $role_object->grantPermission('my custom permission name');
  $role_object->save();
}
```