# How to grant create and update permissions to a custom role?

Tags: 8, users, hooks

I have a new role as "Publisher". I want to grant Publisher 'create' and 'update' permission using code.

My .permissions.yml file looks like this :

```
'delete contact entity':
  title: Delete entity content.
'add contact entity':
  title: Add entity content
'view contact entity':
  title: View entity content
'edit contact entity':
  title: Edit entity content
'administer contact entity':
  title: Administer settings
'publisher contact entity':
  title: Publisher settings
```

I've used 2 functions to allow permissions.
The functions are:

```
 protected function checkAccess(EntityInterface $entity, $operation, AccountInterface $account) {
// Check the admin_permission as defined in your @ContentEntityType
// annotation.
$publisher_permission = $this->entityType->getPublisherPermission();
if ($account->hasPermission($publisher_permission)) {
  return AccessResult::allowed();
}
switch ($operation) {
  case 'edit':
    return AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'edit contact entity');

  case 'update':
    return AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'update contact entity');
}
return AccessResult::neutral();  }


protected function checkCreateAccess(AccountInterface $account, array $context, $entity_bundle = NULL) {
// Check the publisher_permission as defined in your @ContentEntityType
// annotation.
$publisher_permission = $this->entityType->getPublisherPermission();
if ($account->hasPermission($publisher_permission)) {
  return AccessResult::allowed();
}
return AccessResult::allowedIfHasPermission($account, 'edit contact entity');   }
```

Now, If check sitename/admin/people/permissions, the role is created by it doesn't have a tick in the checkbox for `edit contact entity.`

PS: In @ContentEntityType, I've defined publisher permission as:

```
publisher_permission = "publisher contact entity"
```

Comment: Are you looking for `$role->grantPermission()`? See https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/267623/grant-permission-for-custom-role-from-hook-install-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

You may grant your permissions on install time of your module with a simple config in config/install/user.role.publisher.yml (about this):

```
langcode: en
status: true
dependencies: {  }
id: publisher
label: Publisher
weight: 3
is_admin: null
permissions:
  - 'add contact entity'
  - 'edit contect entity'
```

Your code above is not a "grant", it's a runtime-check of users permissions.